# React How do you pin up/show/poster a button with visibility icon (eye) in material ui table?

Tags: reactjs, uibutton, material-ui

I want to show in React a green button with an eye like in my sketch [green button the goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wW6L.png)a  . I did my table  material-ui from material-ui website. However I can't pin up my   `<IconButton><Visibility/></IconButton>` in my website[mywebsitewiththetick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhr91.png). I followed a lot of videos without success. I tried different values im my table but this one shows me  V (tick).

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwqFX.png)
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEElU.png)

I put in "import" :

`import React from 'react';
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';
import IconButton from 'material-ui';
import { Visibility } from '@material-ui-icons';`

What do you think, please ?

Have a good day

Video : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vj27n1ekPJY

Icon Visibility material-ui : 
https://material-ui.com/components/material-icons/

table  material-ui in code sandbox : 
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-yet69?file=/index.js

Comment: I started it all over. I used my own code for codepen and put it in my files have a good day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYrvX.png)

I used my own codepen with html css and javascript babel. I changed js file into jsx file.My tables works. I have done.I find the answer.